# Finding associations for a set of keys

Tags: python

I am writing my first programs in Python and want to be sure my code is good and not too C++-like. Consider the problem of finding all common 'associations' for set of 'keys'.

Data format is

- first line: integer `N`
- `N` lines: key: `association 1 ... association P_1`
- `N+2`th line: integer `K`
- `K` lines: `key 1 ... key T_1`

For each line after `K`, the program should output all common associations for all keys listed.

For example, the correct output for input

> ```
> 10
> 0: even
> 1: odd
> 2: even prime
> 3: odd prime
> 4: even composite notprime
> 5: odd prime
> 6: even composite notprime
> 7: odd prime
> 8: even composite notprime
> 9: odd composite notprime
> 2
> 8 4
> 2 3
> ```

is

> ```
> composite even notprime
> prime
> ```

My code is

```python
f = open('input.txt', 'r') #input file
d = {} #associations
uni = set() #set of all associations

for i in range(int(f.readline())):
  t = f.readline().strip().split(': ') #split into list ('key', 'assoc1 ... assoc P_1')
  d[t[0]] = s = set(t[1].split(' ')) #d : key -> set('assoc1', ..., 'assoc P_1')
  uni |= s #add to uni

for i in range(int(f.readline())):
  #read keys as list and intersect uni and list's associations
  print reduce(lambda assoc, key: assoc & d[key], set(f.readline().strip().split(' ')), uni.copy())
```

How good is my code from the viewpoint of experienced Python programmers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks pretty good for a newcomer to the language. Some comments:

- I don't quite understand why you need `uni`.
- References to `t[0]` and `t[1]`: It's more declarative to unpack tuples/lists and give names to its components -> `something, another_thing = t`
- `for i in range(int(f.readline()))`. I won't say this is bad, but certainly not very declarative. Note that [itertools.islice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) can be used to read N lines from a file object -> `itertools.islice(f, 10)`.
- Python2: Unless you have a compelling reason, use Python 3.
- `reduce(lambda...`. As much as I like functional style, code that uses `reduce` with long lambdas usually looks cryptic. But I think it's still ok to use `reduce` with named functions.
- `int(f.readline())`. Personally I like to give names to values when it's not clear what they stand for. Granted, this may increase the LOC slightly, but I think it's worthwhile. In this case, if we write `number_of_queries = int(f.readline())` and later use the variable, it's easy to see what's going on.

As a first refactor, I'd write:

```
import itertools
import functools

lines = open("input.txt")

# Parse associations
n_associations = int(lines.readline())
associations = {}
for line in itertools.islice(lines, n_associations):
    n, associations_string = line.split(":")
    associations[n] = set(associations_string.split())

# Parse and run queries
n_queries = int(lines.readline())
for line in itertools.islice(lines, n_queries):
    numbers = line.split()
    common = functools.reduce(set.intersection, (associations[n] for n in numbers))
    print(" ".join(common))
```

Ok, now let's take it a step further. Firstly, there are no functions at all, no modularization, that's no good. Secondly, I prefer a functional approach and there is some imperative stuff going on there. That's how I would write it in a more functional and declarative style:

```
def parse_and_execute_queries(path):
    def parse_association(line):
        number, associations_string = line.split(":")
        return (number, set(associations_string.split()))

    def execute_query(associations, query_string):
        numbers = query_string.split()
        common = functools.reduce(set.intersection, (associations[n] for n in numbers))
        return " ".join(common)

    lines = open(path)
    n_associations = int(lines.readline())
    association_lines = itertools.islice(lines, n_associations)
    associations = dict(parse_association(line) for line in association_lines) 
    n_queries = int(lines.readline())
    queries_lines = itertools.islice(lines, n_queries)
    return (execute_query(associations, line) for line in queries_lines)

for query_result in parse_and_execute_queries("input.txt"):
    print(query_result)
```

Comment: I needed `uni` because I didn't know `set.intersect`. Thank you for the reply!